# jQuery doesn't repeat function on different elements?

Tags: jquery

i was playing with some code and ran into an issue whereby a function is only working for the first element, despite setting a variable that grabs the id for the element on which the function run.

This will explain it better http://jsfiddle.net/matt3224/GXjdb/

```
function calcr() {
    var sum = 0;
    var parent = $(':checked').closest('form').attr('id');
    var names = $('#' + parent + ' :checked').map(function () {
        sum += (this.value - 0);
        return this.name;
    }).get().join(',');
    var spans = $('#' + parent + ' .totalisr').text(sum);
}

$('input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"], select').change(calcr);
```

If you could assist me on why this is happening and propose a potential fix that would be awesome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem child is this line `$('#' + parent + ' :checked')`

Select does not have the `checked` property

Supposed to be

```
$('#' + parent + ' :selected')
```

Also need to replace

```
var parent = $(':checked').closest('form').attr('id');
```

with

```
var parent = $(this).closest('form').attr('id');
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/GXjdb/4/)**

Comment: hi, i don't want it to change the value for all three i want each drop down to change its respective value, so i was using id because each one would be different.

Comment: You are welcome :).  But if you want the same to work also with radio or checkboxes , you might need to add a bit of logic.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the :checked *or* the :selected pseudo selector.  You can just use the select element itself to find the parent form you need.

```
var parent = $(':checked').closest('form').attr('id');
```

Change the above to:

```
var parent = $(this).closest('form').attr('id');
```